# 'At least one field is expected inside environment' error in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

When I tried to apply a terraform in order to create a lambda function, I got this error:

```
 Error: At least one field is expected inside environment
```

Here is my terraform module:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = var.lambda_filename
  description = var.description
  runtime = "python3.6"
  environment {
    variables = var.variables
  }
}
```

This error is thrown when `var.variables` is set to null.

How can I fix it?

I am using terraform 0.12.6 and aws provider 2.25.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find a solution: Use `dynamic` in the latest version of terrafrom

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = var.lambda_filename
  description = var.description
  runtime = "python3.6"

  dynamic "environment" {
    for_each = local.environment_map
    content {
      variables = environment.value
    }
  }
}
```

The `environment_map` is created this way:

```
locals {
  environment_map = var.variables == null ? [] : [var.variables]
}
```

Comment: A shorter way to write `any_map == null ? [] : [any_map]` is `any_map[*]`; a "special power" of the splat operators is that if you apply to something that isn't a sequence then it'll produce either an empty list or a single-element list depending on whether the value is null.

Comment: can you add what version you are calling the "latest" version of terraform?

Comment: @ccu That would be Terraform 0.12 and above - https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html - search for "dynamic blocks"

Comment: Also you can just add something like `merge({"LOG_LEVEL":"INFO"}, var.environment_vars_map)` and your map will be never empty

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution above, also remember to set the default value for your variable to null. Eg.

```
variable variables {
  type    = map
  default = null
  description = "My map" 
}
```

Comment: This should be probably be a comment or edit of the other answer, but thanks for the extra information and help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).